# Job interview abroad - Should I ask for reimbursement?

Tags: interviewing, human-resources

I am from Portugal and a company in the UK is interested in hiring me (as a remote worker).
Currently I have passed several technical interviews and a meeting with the CEO, and they told me the next step in the process is a few days work in their office in Manchester.

I would like to know if it is fair and standard to ask the company for:

- Reimbursement for all travel expenditure.
- Accommodation and food, laundry and related.
- Some compensation for my work at their office.

Also I would like to know what is a proper way to ask these requests.

Not sure also regarding how to get these refunds, as I am currently only a candidate not an employee.

How does it work? Should the company pay in advance these expenditures, especially flight tickets?

Did you have any similar experience?

Comment: They *should* cover those expenses as you will be working remote

Comment: Are you sure you will be doing work?  They should reimburse your  expenses.

Comment: @Paparazzi this is a good question, I think they want to introduce me to other members of the team by person, they are also very keen to show me more about their product, and know be a little better. Not sure really if I would be able to do any real job as the meeting in only two days,first time...and to me it sounds not really realistic (but for what I understood they want me to stay in their office 8 hours per day).

Comment: If this is a part of the interview process, two days of expenses plus travel is a lot for them to expect for you to bear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How does it work? Should the company pay in advance these
>   expenditures, specially fly tickets?

Normally, a company will either ask their travel agency to work with you on booking airfare, hotel, and such and they will pay for it - you'll have to pay for your daily expenses (food, etc.) and expense it after. The other option will be that you will pay for everything, retain all your receipts, then submit it to them for reimbursement after your interview. However, in all my experiences, the interested company is very upfront about reimbursements. For those who did, they presented me with both options, and usually will give a per diem amount that I can spend on food and such.

It is odd that they are requiring you to "work" for a few days at their office. I would ask in advance how the compensation for this phase of the interview will go. If they aren't willing to reimburse you then you'll have to weigh the pros and cons of going. If they ignore the question, then I would recommend thinking twice about working for them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, thy just told me is going to be a single day workshop where are going to evaluate me. So I suppose it is not really a "work" day.

Answer (score 4):

If you are still in the interview process you should ask for an expense coverage. They should already have said this and the fact they didn't makes me think they want to pass the expenses to you. They can not expect people to pay from their own pocket for their interview.
Make sure you ask about salary in advance because if you go and do expenses and they make you an offer with low compensation then you completely wasted your time and money

Comment: thanks for your comment, they provided me already with info about salary range

Comment: @Radex, do ask, in the past I attended an interview abroad at 8:30am and they complained when I asked reimbursement for the hotel...

Comment: @Radex:Spending a few days in UK is a lot of money. Why would you go if they don't cover it?

Comment: @Monoandale if they complain about the hotel reimbursement for an early morning interview, then that's where you say you withdraw your application and be grateful you dodged a bullet