# Cannot go to the on-site interview

Tags: interviewing, online, onsite

I landed this interview lately with a really good company. Although it is clear from my profile I am not located in the same country as the work, they ask for an on-site interview. The costs to do such trip are rather high, taking into account I might not get the job at all. How can I ask them/convince them for a first online one? 
Thank you very much

Comment: depending on how your profile got to the person asking for the interview, it may not be clear you are in a different country.  Jet tell them nicely

Comment: Related: [Asking if the company pays travel expenses when Interviewing for an out-of-town job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/23293). [Job interview abroad - Should I ask for reimbursement?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/97555) Although having a telephonic or online interview first would make sense.

Answer (score 9):

Reply and clarify that you can't incur the costs of travelling for the interview:

> Thank you very much for giving me this opportunity. Unfortunately, I am not in a financial position to take advantage of it at the moment. Would a Skype interview suffice instead? Thanks, Andia.

They may offer to cover your costs, agree to a Skype call, or simply cancel your interview. Such is life.

Comment: I might suggest actually mentioning that it's the travel costs specifically that's the problem, to remove ambiguity and potential misunderstandings, and briefly mention where you're currently living, in case they're not aware.

Answer (score 0):

I have to sum up here that communications with the potential new company is very important. I would simply ask them right out if they will provide travel expenses for the interview trip since that will entail travel from where you live to the interview location.

Most reputable companies that are doing external hiring and find a candidate that they feel would be a strong contender for an open position will pay for travel expenses. They may have already made up their mind that they want to get right to the face-to-face interview and so trying to mention a Skype type interview could derail any momentum on their side to see you.

Comment: "will pay for travel expenses."  I think that really depends on the level of the position.  I've a lot of interview requests that required some travel (up to 2-3 hours drive one-way) and was never offered anything for travel.  I'm not complaining, they were entry to mid-level positions and I was just out of school.  So, results may vary.